Are $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ and $U(n)$ transverse at the identity as submanifolds of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$?
We know that if two embedded submanifolds $S_1$ and $S_2$ transversely intersect, then $T_p(S_1 \cap S_2) = T_p(S_1) \cap T_p(S_2)$. On the other hand, we have that $\operatorname{Lie}(SU(n)) \cong T_{I_n}(SU(n))$. We have $SU(n) = U(n) \cap SL(n, \mathbb{C})$, and we know that
$$\operatorname{Lie}(SU(n)) = \mathfrak{su}(n) = \mathfrak{u}(n) \cap \mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{C}) \\= \operatorname{Lie}(SL(n, \mathbb{C})) \cap \operatorname{Lie}(U(n)) \cong T_{I_n}(SL(n, \mathbb{C})) \cap T_{I_n}(U(n)).$$
This is all very suggestive, but I cannot find a good reason why these should be transverse. I believe $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is an embedded submanifold as it is the level set of $\det^{-1}(1)$. Similarly, the unitary matrices are the preimage of $I_n$ under $\Phi$ mapping $A$ to $AA^*$. So I believe these are both embedded submanifolds (though I may be mistaken).

Do you know the definition of transversal intersection? If you do, why don't you try to check it in this case?

Explicitly what are the tangent spaces at $I$ of these two subgroups?

@TedShifrin The tangent spaces are (respectively) the subspaces of the general linear group over $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of the traceless matrices (easy to see this has dim $n^2 - 1$), and the subspace consisting of those matrices such that $A + A^* = 0$. In other words, the complex conjugate of the transpose of A is equal to negative A. This suggests the latter tangent space is the space of purely imaginary symmetric matrices. This has complex dimension $n(n+1)/2$. (cont.)

Now we can argue by dimension counting that if the sum of these two tangent spaces has dimension $n^2$ then it must span tangent space of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$. So it suffices to show that there is a purely imaginary symmetric matrix with non-zero trace? Then we can "fill" the dimension missing from the tangent space of $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$. Thus the sum would have dimension $n^2$ and must then span $M(n, \mathbb{C})$ (tangent space of general linear group). Is this argument correct?

Complex dimension $n^2-1$, yes. No, $\mathfrak u(n)$ is not a complex subspace. It has real dimension $n^2$. Your visualization of it is a bit off.

@TedShifrin Thanks for the response. I accidentally said "complex dimension" but tangent spaces are real vector spaces and so I should have said "real dimension." I can see why $\mathfrak{u}(n)$, matrices in $Gl(n, \mathbb{C})$ for which $A + A^* = 0$, is not a complex vector space (since multiplying by say $i$ would give a matrix that is not purely imaginary). I don't see how it has dimension $n^2$, though. Doesn't the subspace of real symmetric matrices have dimension $n(n+1)/2$? Why should it matter that the entries are purely imaginary in our case?

@TedShifrin On second thought, clearly it has dimension $n^2$ since it is $\operatorname{Lie}(U(n))$ and thus has the same dimension as $U(n)$, which has dimension $n^2$. I admit I have trouble seeing the dimension of the Lie algebra from the equation, but I'll have a think about it. In this case, it follows pretty immediately from dimensions that the manifolds are transverse. Right?

It is not a space of symmetric matrices though. It is the space of anti-Hermitian matrices which have skew-symmetric real part and symmetric imaginary part (they are certainly not purely imaginary)

How do you get the dimension of a Lie group? You figure out the dimension of its Lie algebra. I do not see how you infer transversality just from dimensions. Indeed, are we sure that they are transverse?
